# Durandal activate function call several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewmodel, durandal

The following code cause two calls in the activate function of the taginfos viewmodel, WHY ?

```
$(oTag).fancybox({
   'overlayShow'       : true,
   'width'             : 800,
   'height'            : 500,
   'autoScale'         : true,
   'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
   'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
   'type'              : 'iframe',
   'scrolling'         : 'no',
   'href'              : 'http://localhost:1135/#/taginfos/' + item.tagId
});
```

Comment: which of a million `fancyboxes` this one is?

Comment: I think you'll have to post the code for the view and view model to get help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use jquery plugins inside the activate function. The DOM is not ready and the jquery selector might not find anything to give to fancybox. Put all your jquery plugin calls inside veiwActivated function. This may not be a direct answer to your question

Here is an example: (Look at the question section)
[Fancybox v2 not working with Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387023/fancybox-v2-not-working-with-durandal/16391041#16391041)