# Fancybox v2 not working with Durandal

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, durandal

I am not able to get Fancybox work with Durandal. I am using John Papa's Hot Towel Template as my starting point.

Problem: Whenever I click on the image it is navigating to the image path rather than overlaying it on top of the page.

Libraries: Jquery v 1.9.1 & FancyBox 2.1.4.

View:

```
<section>
    <a class="fancybox" title="Our fresh starters"     href="http://www.preschools4all.com/image-files/little-bunny-foo-foo-1.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.preschools4all.com/image-files/little-bunny-foo-foo-1.jpg"     alt="Our fresh starters" />
    </a>
</section>
```

ViewModel:

```
define(['services/logger', 'services/dataservice'], function (logger, dataservice) {

   var vm = {
        viewAttached: viewAttached,
        activate: activate,
    };

    return vm;

    function activate() {
           //Do something
          // return promise
    }

    function viewAttached() {            
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    }

});
```

BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(
 new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
 .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
 .Include("~/scripts/jquery.fancybox.js")
 .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.js")
);


bundles.Add(
 new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
 .Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css")
 .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
 .Include("~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css")
);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: did you include the fancybox css file?

Comment: Yes, I included jquery.fancybox.css. I have added it to the code snippet.

Comment: It seemed like the problem was with bootstrap.js v 2.3.0

Boostrap 2.3.0 is incompatible with fancybox v2. I upgraded my js files to 2.3.1 and it worked.

P.S.: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to answer my own question until 8 hours from the time I have asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like the problem was with bootstrap.js v 2.3.0

Boostrap 2.3.0 is incompatible with fancybox v2. I upgraded to use bootstrap 2.3.1 and solved my issue.